# Get the sum of array with parallel processing

Tags: c, arrays, sum, pipe, fork

I have an X array of N integers. Basically what I need is to get the sum of the elements using parallel processing with fork() and pipe() with divide and conqueror method.
So in the parent I'm dividing the array into two sub-arrays and pass it to the childs, which are doing the same till there are left 2 or 1 elements in the sub array. Then pass it back to the parents.

My only problem is that at the final, I'm getting some random values and I can't understand where are they coming from.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void divide(int n, int* x, int* sum, FILE** logFile)
{
    // Ha n kisebb vagy egyenlo 1-el, nincs szukseg gyerekfolyamatokra
    if (n <= 2) {
        if (n == 1)
            (*sum) += x[0];
        else if (n == 2)
            (*sum) += (x[0] + x[1]);
        else {
            printf("Wrong data given in input.dat\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        return;
    }

    // pipeToParent
    int pipe2Parent1[2], pipe2Parent2[2];
    int pipe2Child1[2], pipe2Child2[2];

    if (pipe(pipe2Parent1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2Parent2) < 0 || pipe(pipe2Child1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2Child2) < 0) {
        perror("Pipe initialization faield.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    pid_t pid1, pid2;

    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Pid1 fork failed.\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Pid2 fork failed.\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    int i;
    if (pid1 && pid2) {
        // <!--Parent process-->

        // Close unnecesary pipes
        close(pipe2Child1[0]);
        close(pipe2Child2[0]);
        close(pipe2Parent1[1]);
        close(pipe2Parent2[1]);

        // Send half of N and first half of array elements to first child
        int half1 = n / 2;

        write(pipe2Child1[1], &half1, sizeof(half1));
        // Log the first HALF to log.dat
        fprintf(*logFile, "szulo - %d - beirtam 1. gyerekbe(%d): n=%d\n", getpid(), pid1, half1);
        fflush(*logFile);

        for (i = 0; i < half1; i++)
            write(pipe2Child1[1], &x[i], sizeof(x[i]));

        close(pipe2Child1[1]);

        // Send other half of N and other half of elements to second child
        int half2 = n - half1;

        write(pipe2Child2[1], &half2, sizeof(half2));
        // Log the second HALF to log.dat
        fprintf(*logFile, "szulo - %d - beirtam 2. gyerekbe(%d): n=%d\n", getpid(), pid2, half2);
        fflush(*logFile);

        for (i = half1; i < n; i++)
            write(pipe2Child2[1], &x[i], sizeof(x[i]));

        close(pipe2Child2[1]);

        // Wait for child processes to terminate
        wait(NULL);

        // Read sum from child processes
        int sum1, sum2;
        read(pipe2Parent1[0], &sum1, sizeof(sum1));
        close(pipe2Parent1[0]);
        fprintf(*logFile, "szulo - %d - kaptam 1. gyerektol(%d) sum=%d\n", getpid(), pid1, sum1);
        fflush(*logFile);

        read(pipe2Parent2[0], &sum2, sizeof(sum2));
        close(pipe2Parent2[0]);
        fprintf(*logFile, "szulo - %d - kaptam 2. gyerektol(%d) sum=%d\n", getpid(), pid2, sum2);
        fflush(*logFile);

        printf("%d %d %d\n", getpid(), sum1, sum2);

        (*sum) += sum1;
        (*sum) += sum2;

        fprintf(*logFile, "szulo - %d - eredmenyt irtam\n", getpid());
        fflush(*logFile);
        printf("sum=%d\n", *sum);
        return;
    }

    else if (!pid1 && pid2) {
        // <!--First child process-->

        // Close unnecesary pipes
        close(pipe2Parent2[0]);
        close(pipe2Parent2[1]);
        close(pipe2Child2[0]);
        close(pipe2Child2[1]);

        close(pipe2Parent1[0]);
        close(pipe2Child1[1]);

        // Read N from parent and it's array's elements
        int n1;
        read(pipe2Child1[0], &n1, sizeof(n1));
        fprintf(*logFile, "1. gyerek - %d - kiolvastam n=%d\n", getpid(), n1);
        fflush(*logFile);

        int* new_x = (int*) malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            read(pipe2Child1[0], &new_x[i], sizeof(new_x[i]));

        // Close read-end pipe from parent
        close(pipe2Child1[0]);

        if (n1 <= 2) {
            int sum1;
            if (n1 == 2)
                sum1 = new_x[0] + new_x[1];
            else if (n1 == 1)
                sum1 = new_x[0];
            fprintf(*logFile, "1. gyerek - %d - szamoltam: %d\n", getpid(), sum1);
            fflush(*logFile);
            write(pipe2Parent1[1], &sum1, sizeof(sum1));
            fprintf(*logFile, "1. gyerek - %d - beirtam: %d\n", getpid(), sum1);
            fflush(*logFile);
        }
        else
            divide(n1, new_x, sum, logFile);

        close(pipe2Parent1[1]);
        free(new_x);
    }

    else if (!pid2 && pid1) {
        // <!--Second child process-->

        // Close unnecesary pipes
        close(pipe2Parent1[0]);
        close(pipe2Parent1[1]);
        close(pipe2Child1[0]);
        close(pipe2Child1[1]);

        close(pipe2Parent2[0]);
        close(pipe2Child2[1]);

        // Read N from parent and it's array's elements
        int n2;
        read(pipe2Child2[0], &n2, sizeof(n2));
        fprintf(*logFile, "2. gyerek - %d - kiolvastam n=%d\n", getpid(), n2);
        fflush(*logFile);

        int* new_x = (int*) malloc(n2 * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            read(pipe2Child2[0], &new_x[i], sizeof(new_x[i]));

        // Close read-end pipe from parent
        close(pipe2Child2[0]);

        if (n2 <= 2) {
            int sum2;
            if (n2 == 2)
                sum2 = new_x[0] + new_x[1];
            else if (n2 == 1)
                sum2 = new_x[0];
            fprintf(*logFile, "2. gyerek - %d - szamoltam: %d\n", getpid(), sum2);
            fflush(*logFile);
            write(pipe2Parent2[1], &sum2, sizeof(sum2));
            fprintf(*logFile, "2. gyerek - %d - beirtam: %d\n", getpid(), sum2);
            fflush(*logFile);
        }
        else
            divide(n2, new_x, sum, logFile);

        close(pipe2Parent2[1]);
        free(new_x);
    }

    else
        exit(0);

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;

    FILE* in = fopen("input.dat", "r");

    // Check file opener
    if (!in) {
        printf("File couldn't be opened.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(in, "%d ", &n);
    // Beolvasas
    int* x = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(in, "%d ", &x[i]);
    }
    fclose(in);

    // Uj log.dat file letrehozasa
    FILE* logFile = fopen("log.dat", "w");
    // Divide and conqueror metodus hasznalataval kiirjuk a visszakapott osszeget
    int sum = 0;
    divide(n, x, &sum, &logFile);

    FILE* out = fopen("output.dat", "w");
    if (!out) {
        printf("output.dat couldn't be opened.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(out, "A sorozat elemeinek osszege: %d", sum);
    fclose(out);
    fclose(logFile);

    free(x);
    exit(0);
}
```

If my input is:

> 6 1 2 3 4 5 6

then n = 6 and x consists of the above elements
The log file displays:

```
parent - 11794 - written into 1. child(11795): n=3
parent - 11794 - written into 2. child(11796): n=3
2. child - 11796 - read n=3
1. child - 11795 - read n=3
parent - 11796 - written into 1. child(11798): n=1
parent - 11796 - written into 2. child(11800): n=2
parent - 11795 - written into 1. child(11799): n=1
parent - 11795 - written into 2. child(11801): n=2
2. child - 11800 - read n=2
2. child - 11801 - read n=2
1. child - 11798 - read n=1
1. child - 11799 - read n=1
2. child - 11800 - calculated: 11
2. child - 11801 - calculated: 5
1. child - 11798 - calculated: 4
2. child - 11800 - written: 11
1. child - 11799 - calculated: 1
2. child - 11801 - written: 5
1. child - 11798 - written: 4
1. child - 11799 - written: 1
parent - 11795 - received 1. child(11799) sum=1
parent - 11795 - received 2. child(11801) sum=5
parent - 11795 - final sum written
parent - 11796 - received 1. child(11798) sum=4
parent - 11796 - received 2. child(11800) sum=11
parent - 11796 - final sum written
parent - 11794 - received 1. child(11795) sum=32654
parent - 11794 - received 2. child(11796) sum=-2093320960
parent - 11794 - final sum written
```

The process 11794 should receive from 1st child 6 and from 2nd child 15 and it would summarize 21, but it receives 32654 and -2093320960

Comment: this is because there is nothing to read for the two `read` (they return 0), so you use not initialized variables `sum1` and `sum2`

Comment: @bruno that’s strange because I should get those values from child1 and child2 ‘write’

Comment: but both call to `read` return 0 (case `if (pid1 && pid2)`)

Comment: `int nr = read(pipe2Parent1[0], &sum1, sizeof(sum1));
 if (nr == 0)
   fprintf(*logFile, "read nothing 1\n");
 else if (nr < 0)
   fprintf(*logFile, "error 1 : %s\n", strerror(errno));
 else
   fprintf(*logFile, "szulo - %d - kaptam 1. gyerektol(%d) sum=%d\n", getpid(), pid1, sum1);` and same for `pipe2Parent2` and in the log file I have `read nothing 1` and `read nothing 2`

Comment: I did not check `read` result in the other cases. I encourage you to always check the value return by `read` and `write` on a socket, never suppose they are ok